# Flutter dependency issue after upgrade

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

After upgrading flutter to - Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.5, the plugins [audio_service](https://pub.dev/packages/audio_service) and [story_view](https://pub.dev/packages/story_view) seems to have encountered a problem :

> Because app depends on **story_view ^0.11.0** which depends on **rxdart ^0.22.2**, **rxdart ^0.22.2** is required.
> So, because app depends on **rxdart ^0.23.1**, version solving failed.
> pub get failed (1; So, because app depends on **rxdart ^0.23.1**, version solving failed.)
> Process finished with exit code 1.

I am using

- story_view: ^0.11.0
- audio_service: ^0.5.6

Which are both the latest version now. Additionally I haven't added rxdart plugin to my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like both `story_view` and `audio_service` depend on `rxdart`, but they're using incompatible versions which is causing version solving to fail.

There's a few options to move forward here:

- File an issue against the `story_view` plugin requesting they update their `rxdart` dependency to the latest version
- Find `story_view` in your .pub_cache on disk and manually modify the `pubspec.yaml` for your copy on disk (this *should* allow for your `flutter pub get` to perform version solving correctly)
- Create a fork of `story_view`, update it's `pubspec.yaml` to depend on `rxdart: ^0.23.1`, and create a [path dependency](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#path-packages) to it

Obviously, none of these solutions are ideal but that should be able to get you unblocked until `story_view` updates to the newest `rxdart`.

Comment: Thanks worked after changing the rxdart to ^0.23.1 inside the pubspec.yaml in the following location ▸ ⁨flutter⁩ ▸ ⁨.pub-cache⁩ ▸ ⁨hosted⁩ ▸ ⁨pub.dartlang.org⁩ ▸ ⁨story_view-0.11.0▸pubspec.yaml⁩ ,flutter upgrade seems to have created somehow similar issues on other plugins as well.